# Why are these two codes different?

Tags: python

Probably a simple question, but I thought I was doing the same thing while instead i get two different answers, I am trying to calculate the sum of all the prime numbers below 2 million.

```
## THIS WORKS ##
import sympy
ans = 0
for n in range(0, 2000000):
    if sympy.isprime(n):
        ans += n
print(ans)

## THIS ONE DOESNT< BUT IT LOOKS THE SAME TO ME ##
ans = sum(sympy.isprime(num) for num in (range(0, 20000000)))
ans
```

Comment: Sorry i don't know why its coming out all in one line, apologies, it is my first post

Comment: Because in the first case you're summing over n, in the second case you're summing over 1. The second snippet outputs the *count*, not the total.

Comment: 2 reasons- the range is different (count the 0s) and you're summing true and false (i.e. 1 and 0) in the 2nd case rather than the number

Comment: The second one needs to be `sum(num for num in (range(0, 20000000)) if sympy.isprime(num))` to be the same.

Comment: As a side note: underscores can be used to separate numeric literals. I.e. `2000000` can be written like `2_000_000` for better readability. For more info see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/

Comment: Wow my first question I learned so much already thank you so much! I got the logic wrong, and I also had the readability issue at some point lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance you're summing over the value, and the second instance you sum over an integer cast of a boolean.

The following code should do what you expect:

```
ans = sum(n for n in range(0, 2000000) if sympy.isprime(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you sum the primes up to 2000000. In the second, you sum booleans saying whether a number is prime. In other words, first code gives a sum of primes, the second gives their number.

Answer (score 0):

The first example sums the prime numbers.

The second example **counts** them. `sympy.isprime(num)` returns either `True` or `False` (1 or 0) and `sum` sums these ones and zeros, effectively counting the prime numbers in that range.

A one liner equivalent for the first example would be

```
sum(num for num in range(0, 20000000) if sympy.isprime(num))
```

Comment: OMG I have had a long day the logic was wrong thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, you're summing up whether it's prime or not (counting the number of primes), not the value of the primes.  To do that, use this:

```
ans = sum(num for num in (range(0, 20000000) if sympy.isprime(num)))
```